# Variable assignment and functions - this should work right?

Tags: php

I am trying to take a variable from `$_POST`, run `mysql_real_escape_string` and a custom function, `html2text` on it. This should work, right? Or do I need to separate it on separate lines?

```
$orgname = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($orgname)) = $_POST['orgname'];
```

Comment: Why you don't just insert variable `$_POST['orgname']` into `html2txt` function?

Comment: Although I doubt that it works, DO NOT DO SUCH A THING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to do this:

```
$orgname = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['orgname']));
```

Answer (score 1):

That won't work because you can't use the functions return value in write context:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

This code should work (and is more cleaner):

```
$orgname = mysql_real_escape_string( html2txt($_POST['orgname']) );
```